# radio buttons used in an email

Tags: html, email

Using HTML, I have been trying to incorporate radio buttons into an email so the recipient of the email can make a selection and then return the email. The incorporation part appears to be OK, with the recipient appearing able to select an option after Reply has been selected. When the email is received back by the original sender - GMail is being used - the radio buttons are not visible (the text labels are).

Has anybody had success with incorporating radio buttons into an email and receiving back a response?

The HTML used for the radio buttons is shown below:

```
 <fieldset  style='width:35%'>
            <legend>Please provide your gender</legend>
            <input type="radio" id='radm' name="sex" value="male" ><label for="male">Male</label>
            <br />
            <input type="radio" id='radf' name="sex" value="female" ><label for="female">Female</label
</fieldset>
```

Comment: This is dependent on the email client and how it chooses to display HTML.  GMail may strip out the radio buttons.  Have you tried using a different, non-Google email to receive the reply, with a different email client such as Outlook?